# How to prove the angle relationship between adjacent scalene triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I'm trying to help my son prepare for an exam. I am many years out of school. How can I prove the relationship between $\angle ABO$ of the one scalene triangle and the angle $x$ of the other scalene triangle, both pictured below, and explain the solution coherently? Any outside references are welcome, such as YouTube videos, etc. I need to relearn this material too if I am to be of any help.

[image]

Comment: The best resource to learn about this stuff is a geometry textbook, which I'm sure your son has, but if you want an online resource, I have [written a brief overview](https://rmehtany.github.io/notes/MB3/Week13/#circle) of circle properties that might help.

Comment: [This page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/circle-geometry-properties/) from Brilliant can help. I'll try to provide more help if you could explain the exam your son is preparing for, and the topics included.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\angle OBD$ and $\angle OCD$ are right angles by tangency, $\angle COB=180^\circ-x$. Thus, $\angle BAC=90^\circ-\frac x2$ since interior angles are half the measure of their inscribed arcs.

By S-A-S, $\triangle ABD\cong\triangle ACD$. This implies that $\angle ABO=\angle ACO$, and $$\angle ABO+\angle ACO=360^\circ-(360^\circ-\angle COB+\angle BAC)=90^\circ-\frac x2$$So, $\angle ABO=\frac12\left(90^\circ-\frac x2\right)=45^\circ-\frac x4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha = \angle ABO$. Because O is the center of the circle, $\angle BAC = 2\alpha$ and $\angle ACO = \alpha$. $\angle ABO + \angle ACO + \angle BAC = 4\alpha$

DB and DC are tangents, thus $|OC| \perp |DC|$ and $|OB| \perp |DB| \Longrightarrow \angle OCD = \angle OBD = 90^{\circ} \Longrightarrow \angle BOC =180^{\circ}-x$ (The sum of interior angles of OBDC is equal to $180^{\circ} + x + \angle BOC$)

\begin{equation}
4\alpha = 180^{\circ}-x \Longrightarrow \angle ABO = \alpha = 45^{\circ}-\frac{x}{4}
\end{equation}